# TypeError: termSearch.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Necesito que a la hora de seleccionar una provincia en el **select** me devuelva las clínicas que están ubicadas en esa provincia, y al seleccionar una provincia me da este error:

> TypeError: termSearch.toLowerCase is not a function.

Estoy un poco perdido en esta parte del código.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Select, { SingleValue } from 'react-select'
import { getClinic } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import {Clinic} from '@icofcv/common';


export const SearchFilterClinics = () => {

         ////filter

         type OptionType = {
            value: string;
            label: string;
          };
    
          
            const provincesList: OptionType[] = [
                { value: 'Todos', label: 'Todos' },
                { value: 'Alava/Araba', label: 'Alava/Araba' },
                { value: 'Albacete', label: 'Albacete' },
                { value: 'Alicante', label: 'Alicante' },
                { value: 'Almería', label: 'Almería' },
                { value: 'Avila', label: 'Avila' },
                { value: ' Badajoz', label: ' Badajoz' },
                { value: 'Islas Baleares', label: 'Islas Baleares' },
                { value: 'Barcelona', label: 'Barcelona' },
                { value: 'Burgos', label: 'Burgos' },
                { value: 'Cáceres', label: 'Cáceres' },
                { value: 'Cádiz', label: 'Cádiz' },
                { value: 'Castellón', label: 'Castellón' },
                { value: 'Ciudad Real', label: 'Ciudad Real' },
                { value: 'Córdoba', label: 'Córdoba' },
                { value: 'A Coruña/La Coruña', label: 'A Coruña/La Coruña' },
                { value: 'Cuenca', label: 'Cuenca' },
                { value: 'Gerona/Girona', label: 'Gerona/Girona' },
                { value: 'Granada', label: 'Granada' },
                { value: 'Guadalajara', label: 'Guadalajara' },
                { value: 'Gipuzkoa/Guipuzcoa', label: 'Gipuzkoa/Guipuzcoa' },
                { value: 'Huelva', label: 'Huelva' },
                { value: 'Huesca', label: 'Huesca' },
                { value: 'Jaen', label: 'Jaen' },
                { value: 'León', label: 'León' },
                { value: 'Lérida/Lleida', label: 'Lérida/Lleida' },
                { value: 'La Rioja', label: 'La Rioja' },
                { value: 'Lugo', label: 'Lugo' },
                { value: 'Madrid', label: 'Madrid' },
                { value: ' Málaga', label: ' Málaga' },
                { value: 'Murcia', label: 'Murcia' },
                { value: 'Navarra', label: 'Navarra' },
                { value: 'Orense/Ourense', label: 'Orense/Ourense' },
                { value: 'Asturias', label: 'Asturias' },
                { value: 'Palencia', label: 'Palencia' },
                { value: 'Las Palmas', label: 'Las Palmas' },
                { value: 'Pontevedra', label: 'Pontevedra' },
                { value: 'Salamanca', label: 'Salamanca' },
                { value: 'S.C.Tenerife', label: 'S.C.Tenerife' },
                { value: 'Cantabria', label: 'Cantabria' },
                { value: 'Segovia', label: 'Segovia' },
                { value: ' Sevilla', label: ' Sevilla' },
                { value: 'Soria', label: 'Soria' },
                { value: 'Tarragona', label: 'Tarragona' },
                { value: 'Teruel', label: 'Teruel' },
                { value: 'Toledo', label: 'Toledo' },
                { value: 'Valencia', label: 'Valencia' },
                { value: 'Valladolid', label: 'Valladolid' },
                { value: 'Bizkaia/Vizcaya', label: 'Bizkaia/Vizcaya' },
                { value: 'Zamora', label: 'Zamora' },
                { value: 'Zaragoza', label: 'Zaragoza' },
                { value: 'Ceuta', label: 'Ceuta' },
                { value: 'Melilla', label: 'Melilla' },
               
            ]

    const [clinicList, setClinicList] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [clinicListFilteredSelect, setClinicListFilteredSelect] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [filterSelectClinic, setFilterSelectClinic] = useState<SingleValue<OptionType>>(provincesList[0]);
    
    
    const fetchClinicList = async () => {
        getClinic().then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
            setClinicList(response);
            setClinicListFilteredSelect(response)
        }).catch ( (error)  => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });
    }
                                         
                                   

      const handleChangeSelect = (provinceList: SingleValue<OptionType>) =>{
         console.log(provinceList)
         setFilterSelectClinic(provinceList);
         filterSelect(provinceList );
      }

       
      const filterSelect=(termSearch)=>{
        const resultFilterSelect = clinicList.filter((element) => {
          if(element.province?.toString().toLowerCase().includes(termSearch.toLowerCase() )
        
          ){
            return element;
          }
        });
        setClinicListFilteredSelect(resultFilterSelect);
      }

      useEffect (() => {
        fetchClinicList();  
    }, []);

   

    return  (
                <>
                    <div>
                        <h1>Encuentra tu clínica</h1>
                    </div>
                        <div>

                                <Select 
                                    defaultValue={filterSelectClinic}
                                    options={provincesList}
                                    onChange={handleChangeSelect}
                                    
                                    />



                                {
                                    clinicListFilteredSelect.map((clinic) => (
                                        <div>
                                            <div>{clinic.title}</div>
                                            <div>{clinic.propsPhone}</div>
                                            <div>{clinic.mobile}</div>
                                            <div>{clinic.email}</div>
                                            <div>{clinic.province} </div>
                                            <div>{clinic.registry}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </div>

                          
                </>
            )
}
```

Comment: El problema parece estar en la variable `termSearch`, que parece que esperas un String pero recibe otra cosa, revisa qué recibes en el método.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes problemas con los tipos de datos:

```
const filterSelect=(termSearch)=>{
        const resultFilterSelect = clinicList.filter((element) => {
          if(element.province?.toString().toLowerCase().includes(termSearch.toLowerCase() )
        
          ){
            return element;
          }
        });
        setClinicListFilteredSelect(resultFilterSelect);
      }
```

Estas usando typescript así que tienes que explicarle que tipos de datos usas, "termSearch.toLowerCase()" toLowerCase() es un método de string, entonces tienes que garantizar que termSearch se de tipo string por ejemplo así:

```
const filterSelect=(termSearch:string)=>{...}
```

Ese cambio va a lanzar otro error que es cuando llamas a la funcion filterSelect ya que providenceList (que no es una lista sino un objeto, yo cambiaria el nombre) es un objeto de tipo SingleValue | null por lo tanto hay que verificar que no sea null y después enviar providenceList.label por ejemplo así:

```
const handleChangeSelect = (provinceList: SingleValue<OptionType>) => {
    console.log(provinceList)
    setFilterSelectClinic(provinceList);
  
    if(provinceList!=null)
        filterSelect(provinceList?.label);
}
```